# Cannot unzip with zip command line

Tags: windows, command-line, script, shell-script, 7-zip

I am having difficult unpacking a zip to a specific directory.  I am trying to get all contents of subdirectory of the zipped file and not the parent directory.  This is parent directory within zip file;

```
c:\mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0
```

However I want the directories below and was trying to extract with the following command;

```
7z e mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0.zip –o”c:\program files\mongodb” -r
```

I keep getting cannot find archive, I have tried various variations of syntax including dropping quotes, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what is the archive's filename?

Comment: mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0.zip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The man page tells you to put the options first, and

```
 -r[-|0]
          Recurse subdirectories
          (CAUTION: this flag does not do what you think, avoid using it)
```

You can do eiter

```
7z x -o"somedir" mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0.zip
```

to e`x`tract the contents of `mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0.zip` to the `-o`utput directory `"somedir"`, preserving the internal directory structure of the archive.

Or

```
7z e -o"somedir" mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0.zip
```

to `e`xtract every file in the archive to `"somedir"` while flattening the archive, so every file will be saved in `"somedir"`, regardless of the directory structure in the archive. Since your archive contains only one subdirectory with text files, this will come closest to your needs.

Comment: Ok thanks Jasper however the directory it creates is called "mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0" which contains a subdirectory "mongodb" however I need this subdirectory to be the one 7zip extracts and not the parent one.

Comment: Please povide a link to the zip file.

Comment: https://fastdl.mongodb.org/win32/mongodb-win32-x86_64-2008plus-2.6.0.zip

Comment: The `e` approach was almost correct then, except the -r and the option at the end. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Jasper for the answer however when running a batch file it won't allow me to goto next command after unzip process, I will ask another question on their forum at SourceForge for an anwser.

Comment: You mean you dont get your shell prompt back after unpacking is completed?

Comment: Yes that is correct, you can get round this by using "call" for this command and next!